# How to find source of all functions in openssl, e.g. PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY

Tags: c, openssl

I just find it in a .pod file but no more details, where the declaration in the c part?

Comment: You do know that [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) is open source, which means you can easily [get the source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl)?

Comment: Some source code is generated on-the-fly, and that is why the source code is difficult to find.

Comment: It looks like the perl script util/mkdef.pl generates some PEM_read_bio_* functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In crypto/pem/pem.h :

```
/*
 * These macros make the PEM_read/PEM_write functions easier to maintain and
 * write. Now they are all implemented with either: IMPLEMENT_PEM_rw(...) or
 * IMPLEMENT_PEM_rw_cb(...)
 */

...

# define IMPLEMENT_PEM_read_bio(name, type, str, asn1) \
type *PEM_read_bio_##name(BIO *bp, type **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u)\
{ \
return PEM_ASN1_read_bio((d2i_of_void *)d2i_##asn1, str,bp,(void **)x,cb,u); \
}
```

And the RSA + PUBKEY part is in : `crypto/pem/pem_all.c`

Comment: Thank you so much!